# Click event binding only once on input [type='radio']

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am relatively new to jQuery, am using a plugin which creates a multi-step form. It basically envelops all the code in fieldsets and shows one fieldset at a time. It currently moves to the next fieldset when I click on "Next" button.

However am trying to add a functionality where I can move to the next page if I select/check a Radio button.

I have tried to do that by using the trigger and triggerHandler function, but it works only for the first fieldset.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(index){
//$(this).on("click",function(){
    $(".next").triggerHandler("click");
});


});
```

Tried with the commented code also, but still to no avail. I have tried for hours, so here I am now. Thank you for your help.

The complete code and Js is here.

https://jsfiddle.net/5j0hsjrq/#&togetherjs=HlyfJeCq0q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need it to click the correct .next which can be found within each fieldset where each next button is also.

```
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function(index){
      $(this).closest('fieldset').find(".next").triggerHandler("click");
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5j0hsjrq/1/

Comment: Thank you so much, I have choosen your answer as the right one. I can't believe I missed this and spent more than a day. Thanks again.